# How to dynamically change data of Reingold–Tilford Tree using d3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3.js and when i want to display a node's invisible children in Reingold–Tilford Tree, I run into a problem.

When the update() is first called,everything looks fine, but when i click on a circle, there goes the bug. It seems every node in my graph has changed its name or depth but does not display its change in my graph.

I've been working on this all day and any suggestion will be appreciated!
my code is here:

```
 <i> function update(root) {
        //var root = makeD3Data(myroot);
        // if(root==compareroot){
        //     console.log("yes");
        // }else{
        //     console.log("no");
        // }
        // compareroot = root;
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
            links = tree.links(nodes);

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(links)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", diagonal)
            .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
                //return d.target.traffic-100 + "px";
                return "1.5px";
            });

        // force
        //     .nodes(nodes)
        //     .links(links)
        //     .start();


        var tooltip = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("z-index", "10")
            .style("visibility", "hidden")
            .text("a simple tooltip");
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
                //return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
            })
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text(function() {
                    if (d.depth == 3 && d.name != "i am C" && d.name != "i am B" && d.name != "i am A") {
                        return "bytes=" + d.value.bytes + " sip=" + d.value.sip + " dip=" + d.value.dip + " divip=" + d.value.devip +
                            " time=" + d.value.time + " protocol=" + d.value.protocol + " sport=" + d.value.sport + " dport=" + d.value.dport +
                            " pkts=" + d.value.pkts;
                    } else if (d.name == "i am C" || d.name == "i am B") {
                        return d.name;
                    }
                    return "";
                });
            })
            .on("mousemove", function() {
                return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function() {
                return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
            });

        // var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        //     .duration(750)
        //     .attr("transform", function(d) {
        //         return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        //     });
        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .on("click", click)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                if (d.name == "i am B" || d.name == "i am A" || d.name == "i am C") {
                    return "steelblue";
                }
            });
        //.call(force.drag);

        //original text for each node
        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                // if(d.depth==3){
                //  return "bytes="+d.value.bytes+"sip="+d.value.sip+"dip="+d.value.dip;
                // }
                return d.name;
            });
    }

    function click(d) {
        if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
            //if(d.name=="i am B"){
            //console.log(root);
            // var newone = jQuery.extend(true,{},d.parent._children[0]);
            // d.parent.children.push(newone) ;
            // d.parent._children = [];
            //d.parent._children.splice(0,1);
            var newchild = {
                "traffic": 1,
                "children": [],
                "name": "tmpqueue"
            };
            d.children.push(newchild);
            // }
            update(root); //[80,8080] has changed its depth
        }
    }</i>
```

when i click a node, i got its four invisible children displayed:
here is my click method:

```
 function click(d) {
        if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
            if (d.name == "i am A") {
                //console.log(root);
                var i=0;
                while( i < d.parent._children.length) {
                    var newone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, d.parent._children[i]);
                    if (newone.name != null) {

                        d.parent.children.push(newone);
                        update();
                        d.parent._children.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            update();
        }
 }
```

But every path between the new child and its parent is somehow put offset the parent;
when i display a child,i called the update method to reload my tree layout.

Here is my update method

```
  function update() {
       var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])
            .separation(function(a, b) {
                return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth;
            });
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
            links = tree.links(nodes);
       var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(links,function(d){
                return d.source.name+"-"+d.target.name+"-"+d.source.traffic+d.target.traffic;
            })
            .enter()
            .insert("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", diagonal)
            .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
                //return d.target.traffic-100 + "px";
                return "1.5px";
            });

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes,function(d){
                return d.name+" "+d.traffic;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
                //return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
            });


        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .on("click", click)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                if (d.name == "i am B" || d.name == "i am A" || d.name == "i am C") {
                    return "steelblue";
                }
            });
        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Could you tell us how your code is different from examples like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)? It's quite hard to tell what's going on with a large chunk of code and there're a lot of working examples that you could start from.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff When I add node to a Reingold–Tilford Tree, I find that actually the number of children for certain parent node increases by using Firebug, but the new-born children are not presented in the webpage. Could you please give me a hand?

Comment: As a start, you should give a matching function to `.data()`, e.g. `function(d) { return d.name; })`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks a lot. It works!  However, another problem comes out. The location of the source side of the new link is not exactly at its source node. Margin exists between them. How should I do to make they emerge into one node?

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff May i add a force to the Reingold–Tilford Tree ?

Comment: In principle you could, but I don't see a plausible use case for this.

Comment: it seems that when a Reingold–Tilford Tree is generated,every child's location is static ,what if i wanna add more children ? How to place the new ones?

Comment: You need to run the layout again.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have provided details in my work,would you please do me a favor ?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have solved my problem.I forgot to remove my old svg element.Thank you very much!